# Query in Jquery IF statement

Tags: php, jquery

I have a jquery save script like :

```
naam = prompt('Give a name for your file.');

if(naam != null)
{   
  var div_contents = $("#print").html();
  $.post("save.php", { 'contents': div_contents,'naam':naam });
  alert('Your file is save as :  '+ naam);  
  window.location.replace("index.php?id=latest");
} 
else
{
  alert('Not saved');
}
```

I save a div in save.php which creates an new id in the database

What I want to achive is were

```
window.location.replace("index.php?id=latest");
```

id=latest must become (id=id from last saved file).

I tried

```
$q = "select MAX(id) from Moodboards";
$result = mysql_query($q);
$data = mysql_fetch_array($result);
$MBId = $data[0];
window.location.replace("index.php?id="+MBId);
```

and

```
var MBID = 
<?php
$q = "select MAX(id) from Moodboards";
$result = mysql_query($q);
$data = mysql_fetch_array($result);
$MBId = $data[0];
echo $MBId ?>
window.location.replace("index.php?id="+MBId);
```

They both failed.

How can I run the query in the if(naam !=null) statement?

Comment: Your approach is totally flawed, both client and server side. Consider learning modern web development from scratch, starting from ideas and going then to implementation.

Comment: moonwave99 so you say it is imposible to use php in a jquery script?

Comment: @SvenB it's not impossible, you just don't distinct client and server side programming ..

Comment: what does ajax do then? you can run php indirect via jquery i thought

Comment: You don't have to think of "php inside jquery", you have to understand HTTP protocol - then you'll get to know that your browser [i.e. the client] performs a request to your server [where php scripts reside], and you answer back with a response. I've always found [this resource](http://symfony.com/doc/2.1/book/http_fundamentals.html) very enlightening.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

At first place you must fix your jQuery POST... You don't use POST respond which is wrong.. You should wait for it and then continue with other actions

```
naam = prompt('Give a name for your file.');

if(naam != null)
{   
  var div_contents = $("#print").html();
  $.post("save.php", { 'contents': div_contents,'naam':naam }, function(responde){
     if(responde.id)
        window.location.replace("http://yoururl.com/index.php?id="+responde.id);
     else
        alert("No responde...");
  }, "json");
} 
else
{
  alert('Not saved');
}
```

For better results I suggest you to use JSON data in that post/respond..
At your PHP code you have to set:

```
<?php
$q = "select MAX(id) from Moodboards";
$result = mysql_query($q);
$data = mysql_fetch_array($result);
$MBId = $data[0];
echo json_encode(array('id'=>$MBId)); 
exit();
?>
```

P.S. For window.location.replace please set your FULL url: `"http://localhost/index.php?id="` OR atleast put slash at start of it `"/index.php?id="`

Comment: I am not getting any response not a refres and not the alert not saved :( i replaced the redirect with alert("Saved"); also no response

Comment: it says save.php status 200 OK

Comment: I dont know where the error is the code dosnt reach the redirect code.

Comment: The save.php runs cause it is saved in the database

Answer (score 0):

Solution

```
if(naam != null)
{       
 var div_contents = $("#print").html();
 $.post("save.php", { 'contents': div_contents,'naam':naam });
 alert('Uw moodboard is opgeslagen als '+ naam);    
 window.location.replace("index.php?id=<?php $q = "select MAX(id) from Moodboards";
 $result = mysql_query($q);
 $data = mysql_fetch_array($result);
 $MBId = ($data[0] + 1); echo "$MBId";?>");
}
```

This Works for me , i didnt need to make a jquery var i could echo the variable in php.

And i had to add 1 cause the sql query is loaded when the page is loaded.

So the file isn't saved yet when i get the highest id.

Comment: you still arn't using the $.POST(); correctly ... you send some info to the save.php but you never check if save.php is succesfull or not.